# How to connect with to the expo. Problem with Network request failed

Tags: react-native, expo

guys.
I have some problem witch last conversion to the expo.

Error:, [TypeError: Network request failed]

- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error

- screens/HomeScreen.js:76:13 in fetch.then.then._catch$argument_0

- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:458:30 in callImmediates

- [native code]:null in callImmediates

- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:407:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:143:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:142:17 in __guard$argument_0

- [native code]:null in flushedQueue
- [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

I checked the IP.
Can you help me?

Comment: The ip is your localhost, if the lan connection mode not working try to use tunnel. Also it's possible that the problem is relative to the cache, so try to restart with `expo r -c`

Comment: doesn't work :(